# Get a list of attributes wtih converted type from object list java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I know how to get a list of attributes from an object list into a new list. 
But how about if I also want to convert the type from `int` to `long`. For example, if I have a user class with a method called get userId (which is `int` type) and  `myUserList` is a list of user objects.

```
List<Integer> userIdList = myUserList.stream()
  .map(User::getUserId)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So I could get a list of userId with `int` type. How about if I want to convert `int` to `long`. I tried this code:

```
 myUserList.stream()
  .map(Long::intValue(User::getUserId))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I had an error `can not resolve method static...`.
May anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: How about `.map(user -> (long) user.getUserId())` or `.map(user -> Long.valueOf(user.getUserId())` ?

Comment: thanks. Do you want to write your answer below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert an int to a long by casting

```
.map(user -> (long) user.getUserId())
```

or (since it needs to be boxed anyway to go into a list), you can use `Long.valueOf`.

```
userList.stream()
        .map(user -> Long.valueOf(user.getUserId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why not use mapToLong() instead of map() in the first place ?

Comment: @FairPlay You can't put `long`s in a list. They'd have to be boxed back into objects anyway.